# When can I use Cyberfeeder's recurring credit with icebreakers?

Tags: android-netrunner

In Android: Netrunner, [Cyberfeeder](http://netrunnercards.info/card/01005/) is a piece of hardware that reads:

> 1 [Recurring credit]
>
> Use this credit to pay for using **icebreakers** or for installing **virus** programs.

I'm interested in the "using icebreakers" clause. I know I can use it for icebreakers' paid abilities, such as `1 [Credit]: +1 strength` or `1 [Credit]: break ice subroutine`, but I was wondering if it can also be used for other effects like this one of Darwin's:

> When your turn begins, you may pay 1 [Credit] to place one virus counter on Darwin.

**Does "use" apply to this kind of cost, or just to paid abilities?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is answered in the [Android: Netrunner FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%20FAQ.pdf) (page 10):

> *Can the Runner use the recurring credit on Cyberfeeder to pay for using Femme Fatale’s bypass ability or Darwin’s gaining counters ability?*
>
> Yes. Triggering any ability on an icebreaker is considered to be using it.

Comment: Great, as I suspected. Just wasn't sure what counted as an "ability".

Comment: Cyberfeeder doesn't say it has to be used for a paid ability, just for using. You can use it to increase Atman's strength too!